# else if javascript loop not working

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

I am trying to count number of occurrences of each item in the csv. My csv is like:

```
date             item
8/10/2015       mobile
1/25/2015       mobile
10/28/2015      mobile
11/9/2015       mobile
8/2/2015        mobile
9/24/2015 0:00  laptop
9/30/2015 0:00  laptop
5/15/2015 0:00  laptop
7/7/2015 0:00   laptop
```

I am using if else to compare the occurrences. But it is not comparing the strings and it is just incrementing the counter.

My code is as follows:

```
    <div>
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="onChange()">
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
    </select>
   </div>
<script>
    function onChange(){
        var selectobject  = document.getElementById("mySelect");
        var MBct = 0;
        var LPct = 0;
        d3.csv("item2.csv", function(error,data) {
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                var date  = d.date;
                var item = d.item;
                a = d.date.split(" ",1);
                b=a[0].split("/");
                d.year = b[2]*1;
                console.log("MBct:"+MBct);
                if(selectobject.value == d.year){
                    console.log("Entered if loop:selectobject.value="+selectobject.value+" ,d.year="+d.year);
                    console.log("item:"+item);


    if(d.item === "mobile"){
                    MBct = MBct + 1;
                    console.log("MBct:"+MBct);
                }
                else if(d.item === "laptop"){
                    LPct = LPct + 1;
                    console.log("LPct:"+LPct);
                }
                else console.log("not present");
    })})}
</script>
```

My output should be like:

```
MBct:5 , LPct:4
```

It is coming like: MBct:9,LPct:0

Anyone any idea??`

Comment: Ur function closing bracket is missing

Comment: did you try to debug with chrome inspector or similar tool?

Comment: If you had indented your code properly, you would have seen it's missing a bunch of closing braces. I'm frankly surprised it even _works_.

Answer (score 0):

You're `d3.csv(`, `function(error) {` and the most important `data.forEach(function(d) {` brackets are not close.

EDIT:
See youre javascript in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/HollyPony/my5rcqkr/1/

Youre brackets are not matching ...

Protips: Use an IDE to automatic close bracket when you open one. Or old school way, begin to close youre brackets manually and THEN write in.

Comment: Tested in jsTester : www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html
It's invalid.
Tested in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/HollyPony/my5rcqkr/1/ . Batch closing brackets.
Tested by my hands ... same results :/